# Modeling non symmetric quadric

Tags: euclidean-geometry, quadratics, quadratic-forms

Do you know a way to model what I would call a non-symmetric quadric surface?

see the pictures :

[image: side view] ,

[image: top view]

Comment: What do you mean by modelling? You mean write in cartesian coordinate an equation to describe those surface by only looking at it?

Comment: More context might help us. Where do the pictures come from? What kind of model do need? What do you need it for?

Comment: By modeling I mean having an equation giving the surface with variable coefficient allowing to fit the experimental surface.
The model comes from the propagation of a Gaussian beam through a cylindrical interface.